# Sequence of different pairs (simple algorithmic question)

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, console

everyone. I've this small task to do:

> There are two sequences of:
>
> 1. Pairs of numbers (A[0],B[0]), (A[1],B[1]), ... , (A[n],B[n]), where all items in sequence A are different.
> 2. Numbers C[0], C[1], ... , C[m].
>
> For each item C[k] of the sequence C print:
>
> ·        Either item B[i]  if there is such i  that C[k]=A[i],
>
> ·        Or zero if not.
>
> · Input:
>    "1 2 3 4 5 6 -1 1 2 -1". 
>    Output:
>    "2 0"

My code is below (with commentary to explain the 'logic' behind it):

```
Dictionary<int, int> res = new Dictionary<int, int>(); // initialing dictionary for holding pairs
var input = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); // parsing the input
var len = Array.IndexOf(input, -1); // for the parsing purpose

for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 2) // filling in that dictionary with pairs
{
    res.Add(input[i], input[i + 1]);
}

for (var i = len + 1; i < input.Length - 1; i++) // traversing through array C[k]
{
    if (res.ContainsKey(input[i]))
    {
        Console.Write(res[input[i]]); // finding associated value with the found key
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(0); // task requirement
    }
}
```

So, the problem is that I can only surpass 8/10 test cases. The last two of them say - "wrong result". Which actually is quite surprising for me, as I thought it's an easy task.

Please, elaborate, what is wrong with this code (approach). Any advice is highly appreciated regarding performance, parsing input, etc. As I don't have anyone to even tell that I'm doing wrong/there is better way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Where's `C` in the example input?

Comment: Between those -1 numbers. So in the example, C[2]{1, 2}.

Comment: And do you know what the test case inputs are, or are they hidden? Try stripping spaces from the output `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: Hidden. This would be very easy if they were not and I would probably be not asking here for the help :) Tbh, I don't think formatting is the case as 8 tests are passing.

Comment: Only things I can see in this code is you are not accounting for odd numbers of input while creating the dictionary which might fail in i+1 case. So there is no B[i] for an equivalent A[i]?

Also what if you receive the same A[i] while hydrating the dictionary, probably need to account for that too?

Comment: @adityap that's assuming the test program also scores the robustness of the solution with bad inputs; this is rarely the case with these types of problems.

Comment: @adityap Regarding i+1 - it's guaranteed that it will be even, as they are pairs. Regarding second point about hydrating, I'm sorry but I can't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @Monstryyy So could you have an input for A,B as 1 2 1 3? The value of B after the first for loop will be 3. Is that expected?

Comment: The task states (see above): "where all items in sequence A are different.". So I guess there is no way there are: "1 2 [and here again 1] 3".

Comment: I was thinking the final resultant has A sequence as different which explained the Dictionary before. But now I get it

Comment: One more thing, the Output you show is "2[space]0" which will not be the case with current Console.Write you have if that is of concern with test cases. But this would also mean all your test cases should fail :/

Comment: I've omitted those formatting parts of the code as they take more space and bring no information. I think it's not about formatting when 80% of test cases are passing, it's more about logic. I suppose, at least.

Comment: Adityap has a good point; since you don't know what the tests are, how would you know if none of the 8 tests you passed expected only one number?

Comment: Yeah, I can't be sure as I don't see them. I thought there is some kind of bug or broken logic in my solution that could be seen by someone. I guess it's not about it then. The reason is that I've done many tasks like this one and test cases were working properly..

Comment: Well just to be on the safe side, add a `Console.Write(" ")` at the end of the loop, and see if you pass the tests.

Comment: It's there :) I'm sorry, I probably should submit the whole code here, not just the main parts as it creates unneeded confusion.

Comment: Yeah and make sure you account for single resultant number verses multiple. So effectively end up trimming your results at the end if need be (or vice-verse depending on which works out since we do not know what the test's expected output is)

Comment: Just putting it out there - Is -1 expected as a legal separator of sequences by tests?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that B does not contain -1? I could see that it could, as you should take A and B in pairs. But your code takes the 1st -1 as the separator.

Comment: Yeah, -1 is only the delimiter. Always.